# find the value of $\sum_{n=0}^{2016} \frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n} a_{n}}{4n+1}$ (details inside)

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If  $(1+x)^{2016}  =  a_{0}+a_{1}x + a_{2}x^{2} +  \cdots  + a_{2016}x^{2016} \ \ \ $ when    $a_{n}$ is coefficient of $x^{n}$

Then ,  find the value of $\ \ \ \frac{a_{0}}{1}-\frac{a_{1}}{5} + \frac{a_{2}}{9} - \frac{a_{3}}{13}+\cdots +\frac{a_{2016}}{8065}  $

**My note**: $\left (\frac{a_{0}}{1}  + \frac{a_{2}}{9}   +\frac{a_{4}}{17}   + \cdots + \frac{a_{2016}}{8065}   \right ) - \left (\frac{a_{1}}{5}  + \frac{a_{3}}{13}   +\frac{a_{5}}{21}   + \cdots + \frac{a_{2015}}{8061}   \right )$

$ = \sum_{n=0}^{1008}\frac{\binom{2016}{2n}}{8n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^{1007}\frac{\binom{2016}{2n+1}}{8n+5}$  $\ \ \ \ = \frac{1}{8065} + \sum_{n=0}^{1007} \frac{2016!}{\left ( 2016-2n \right )!\left ( 2n+1 \right )!} \left ( \frac{2n+1}{8n+1} - \frac{2016-2n}{8n+5}\right ) $

I got stuck to this problem all day , I can't rearrange the final above to collapse them.

Thank you in advance , all of your solution light me up for keep practicing mathematics.

Comment: Look at the function $\sum_{n=0}^{2016} \frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}a_n\cdot x^{4n+1} }{4n+1}$. What can be said about it? Does its _derivative_ look familiar, by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ivan Neretin is right. You have
$$
\text{Your sum}=\int_0^1(1-x^4)^{2016}dx=\prod_{j=1}^{2016}\left(1-\frac1{4j}\right)
=\frac{\Gamma \left(2016\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \Gamma (2017)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you.  How can I read about more information of this lesson in mathematic ?