# Integrate $\int_0^1 x^n \prod_{i=1}^q(a_i-x)^{m_i} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, binomial-theorem, products

I wish to find the value of the integral
$$
\int_0^1 x^n \prod_{i=1}^q(a_i-x)^{m_i} dx,
$$
where $n,m_i,q$ are positive integers and $a_i \geq 1$ for all $i$.
I am hoping at the end to find a computationally less demanding formula.

I tried to expanding the product of powers following @Jonas to arrive at an expression without integration. But... it is a costly product of summations that I don't see how to convert back to a product of powers because of the denominator in terms of $r_i$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1  & x^n  \prod_{i=1}^q (a_i-x)^{m_i} dx \\
&= \int_0^1 x^n \prod_{i=1}^q \sum_{r=0}^{m_i} \binom{m_i} r a_i^{r} (-x)^{m_i-r}dx \\  
&=\int_0^1 x^n \sum_{r_1=0}^{m_1} \binom {m_1}{r_1} {a_1}^{r_1} (-x)^{m_1-r_1}\cdots\sum_{r_q=0}^{m_q} \binom {m_q} {r_q} {a_q}^{r_q} (-x)^{m_q-r_q} dx \\
& =\int_0^1 \sum_{r_1=0}^{m_1} \binom {m_1}{r_1} {a_1}^{r_1}{(-1)^{m_1-r_1}}\cdots\sum_{r_q=0}^{m_q} \binom {m_q} {r_q} {a_q}^{r_q}{(-1)^{m_q-r_q}} x^{n+\sum_{i=1}^qm_i-\sum_{i=1}^qr_i} dx \\
&=\sum_{r_1=0}^{m_1} \binom {m_1}{r_1} {a_1}^{r_1}{(-1)^{m_1-r_1}}\cdots\sum_{r_q=0}^{m_q} \binom {m_q} {r_q} {a_q}^{r_q}{(-1)^{m_q-r_q}}\int_0^1  x^{n+\sum_{i=1}^qm_i-\sum_{i=1}^qr_i} dx \\ 
&=\sum_{r_1=0}^{m_1} \cdots \sum_{r_q=0}^{m_q} \binom {m_1}{r_1} \cdots \binom {m_q} {r_q}  \frac {{(-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^qm_i-\sum_{i=1}^qr_i}} a_1^{r_1} \cdots a_q^{r_q} }{{n+1+\sum_{i=1}^qm_i-\sum_{i=1}^qr_i}}.
\end{align}

Due to the number of terms $m_1\cdots m_q$, it seems computationally infeasible to carry out this sum directly. I was hoping to obtain a nice answer as in [Why $\int_0^1(1-x^4)^{2016}dx=\prod_{j=1}^{2016}\left(1-\frac1{4j}\right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184044/why-int-011-x42016dx-prod-j-12016-left1-frac14j-right?rq=1). Any hints in this direction, or arguments why no nice expression exists will be appreciated!

Comment: what work have you done on the problem? generally, you should research and try to solve the problem yourself before posting and include the effort you've done in the text. See this part of [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/274085)

Comment: I edited to introduce an index $i$ to $m$, i.e. $m_i$

Comment: So are $m_i$ all different or is $m_i=m$ for every $i$?

Comment: @kingW3 $m_i$ are different in general,

Comment: $a_i \ge 1$ for all $i$, correct?

Comment: yes @becko, $a_i \ge 1$ for all $i$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: thank you @Jonas, I edited to explicit my trying using the binomial expansion. An expression that commut the $\prod$ with the $\sum$ would be the answer, but I don't have this expression.

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^q\sum_{r=0}^{m_i} \binom{m_i}{r} a_i^r x^{m_i-r} = \sum_{r_1=0}^{m_1}\sum_{r_2=0}^{m_2}\cdots \sum_{r_q=0}^{m_q} \prod_{i=1}^q \binom{m_i}{r_i} a_i^{r_i} x^{m_i-r_i}$.

Comment: I edited following product expansion of @Jonas,... Oh! forget to evaluate limit integral. Bu the issue with the denominator remain.

Comment: In the expansion, I think the sum should start at $r=0$ and there should be $(-1)^{m_i-r}$.

Comment: @jss Are you looking for a specific answer? Do you have a reason to expect that the sum can be computed with a nice answer?

Comment: @Jonas I need it for computation, first I wanted to remove the integral if possible, now have to sum over ~$m^q$ terms

Comment: @Marty I edited to correct for $r=0$ and care for sign.

Comment: @jss So you are hoping to find a formula which it is computationally less demanding?

Comment: @Jonas yes, at the end

Comment: @jss I tried to clarify the question. I apologize if I missed the point.

Comment: @Jonas I edited to clarify the point on computational demand, ... you helped.

Comment: So, I am open to add other clarifications to my question, so as to remove the ON HOLD.

Comment: @JonasDahlbæk Do you have a reason to expect that it *can't* be computed with a nice answer?

Comment: Why is this question on hold? @kingW3 It seems to me that it is on topic and the OP explained what he had tried.

Comment: @becko The question was missing context when it was posted (look at the edit history), currently after the edit this post entered the reopen queue where people can vote to reopen this post so far there are 4 out of 5 reopen votes (including mine).

Comment: @becko Not aside from my personal experience that most things can't.